# Want to turn Wordpress into a paid subscription directory

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, directory, subscription, user-registration

I need to create a paid subscription directory where people can register their business and enter its details.

Subscriptions should be paid on a monthly or yearly basis.

Business details include typical fields such as: description, address, phone number, zip code, etc.

The idea is that people can create their user as usual, but all the data about their business should be entered in a custom post type. The reason I want this is because I can easily add new fields to a custom post type and also can assign different custom taxonomies, such as neighborhood, business type, etc

**Question #1: how do I restrict each user to a single post? When a user signs up, a post should be created and assigned to his username automatically.**

**Question #2: I also need to offer paid membership per month or per year. How can integrate such a feature with a payment gateway, such as Paypal for example?**

I don't expect an exact response for these questions, but it would be great if I could get some guideance on where to get started.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are all kinds of role assignment and ecommerce plugins available: it's best to start with a search of what's already out there: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/

Answer (score 1):

1: I achieved this once by using a combination of 2 plugins: user roll editor and front-end-editor. One lets you assign specific abilities to each user and the other, as probably obvious, allows you to let users edit posts from the front-end. So, you can set any user with the roll "Member" to be able to "Edit own posts" but not "create posts" or "delete posts" etc.

I'm sure there *has* to be a way to make wordpress auto generate a new post assigned to a specific user upon login, but I've yet to have a need for/discover that yet. When I did this for my site, I just created a post for them.

2: s2 membership is what you need.. I actually just did a website for a client that was similar to yours. s2 membership lets you assign membership rolls to each user and adds a new selection to posts/pages so you can set what level of members use them. IE: You can have a silver, gold, and platinum memberships and control what each level can use very easily. I've never seen another plugin with this much power. It takes a bit to set up, but it's worth it.

On another note, you could always purchase a copy of gravity forms. That mixed with the gravity forms directory plugin and the custom-post-type plugin would allow you to let users submit their information and it would be automatically displayed in a very nice directory list. I've used this combo before and it's awesome.